# Can't find our app in G Suite Marketplace search results

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Our app isn't showing up in the G Suite Marketplace search results whenever we search for it by name or via terms we know are in its description.

The direct link to our app's marketplace listing still works but it isn't showing up in the search results at all.

I've checked the manifest file and everything seems to be in order when I compared it to the sample here: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing#resources_youll_need

Sidenote: I got in touch with Google Support via chat and even they couldn't point me to where exactly I should get help with this. Posting this here in hopes someone knows of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I've read in this [post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/3xdNgMGECQA;context-place=forum/apps), it appears the app is not allowed to be installed for non admin users so therefore the search results will not show the app. However, your app might take few minutes to several hours appear in search result. Check this [Access Marketplace apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172981?hl=en&ref_topic=1056394) support page where it stated that *"Most apps are available immediately after deployment. In some cases, there may be a delay of up to 24 hours before the application is displayed."* Try to check on the next day and see if it works.